# MySQL Invalid use of group function when using max()

Tags: mysql

In my database, each enquiry can have a number of bookings associated with it. Each booking will have a number of people (pax) who the booking relates to. I want to sum the maximum value of pax for each enquiry (e.g. if there were 3 bookings, with pax = 3, 3, 4 then I would want to use 4) for each enquiry. Currently I have this:

```
SELECT SUM(MAX(b.pax))  AS `pax`
FROM enquiry e

LEFT JOIN booking b ON b.enquiry_id = e.id
```

But it is returning the error 'Invalid use of group function'. What am I doing wrong? If I don't use 'max' then it is summing all values of pax instead of just 1 per enquiry, and if I use 'GROUP BY e.id' then it will not return a single number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use two aggregate functions this way, you can do this instead:

```
SELECT SUM(MaxPax) AS Total
FROM
(
    SELECT MAX(b.pax)  AS MaxPax
    FROM enquiry e
    LEFT JOIN booking b ON b.enquiry_id = e.id
    GROUP BY b.enquiry_id
) AS t;
```

So, the inner query, will give you the max `pax` for each inquiry. Then, in the outer query you can get the sum using `SUM`.

Comment: Probably important to note that the sub query is required to have the `t` alias, otherwise it will fail.